# machine learning pipeline transform error

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to follow a project by neuralnine called titanic survival prediction on
youtube. In this part we want to fill columns with non interger values with some values
using this method below. I am using jupyter notebook in pycharm.it seems ok until the error in cell 5, what could be causing it. For [reference](https://youtu.be/fATVVQfFyU0?si=ps_mHbJkploM0oPS), from around [21:17 - 34:28].

```
# cell 1:
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2)
for train_indices, test_indices in split.split(titanic_data, titanic_data[['Survived', 
'Pclass', 'Sex']]):
    strat_train_set = titanic_data.loc[train_indices]
    strat_test_set = titanic_data.loc[test_indices]

# cell 2:
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

class AgeImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")
        X['Age'] = imputer.fit_transform(X[['Age']])
        return X
    
# Cell 3    
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder    
class FeatureEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        encoder = OneHotEncoder
        matrix = encoder.fit_transform(X[['Embarked']]).toarray()
        
        column_names = ["C", "S", "Q", "N"]
        
        for i in range(len(matrix.T)):
            X[column_names[i]] = matrix.T[i]
        
        matrix = encoder.fit_transform(X[['Sex']]).toarray()
        
        column_names = ["Female", "Male"]
        
        for i in range(len(matrix.T)):
            X[column_names[i]] = matrix.T[i]
        
        return X

# Cell 4
class FeatureDropper(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return X.drop(["Embarked", "Name", "Ticket", "Cabin", "Sex", "N"], axis=1, errors="ignore")

# cell 5
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([("ageimputer", AgeImputer),
                 ("featureencoder", FeatureEncoder()),
                 ("featuredropper", FeatureDropper())])


# Then in this cell:    
strat_train_set = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)
```

I get the following error:

```
"""AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fit' """
```

Comment: fix your formatting and indentations

Comment: where exactly?  remember am using jupyter notebook so i don't really suspect indentation, i have tried to copy that youtube video exactly as it is

Comment: it's not about the code in your notebook, but the code here in your question. it's unreadable due to the messed up formatting and indentations

Comment: Include complete error traceback.